# carbon emacs yank results in images

Tags: mac, emacs, elisp

On the default install of Carbon Emacs on OS X, copying a file from Finder and yanking it into emacs results in just the icon being displayed.

How would I go about customizing it so it instead gives the file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to disable all image yanking (drag and drop still works if I really want an image in there) by overriding a function declared in mac-win.el (uncompiled file not included in default install.)

in my .emacs:

```
;; prohibit pasting of TIFFs
(defun x-selection-value (type)
  (let ((data-types '(public.file-url
                       public.utf16-plain-text
                       com.apple.traditional-mac-plain-text))
    text)
    (while (and (null text) data-types)
      (setq text (condition-case nil
             (x-get-selection type (car data-types))
           (error nil)))
      (setq data-types (cdr data-types)))
    (if text
    (remove-text-properties 0 (length text) '(foreign-selection nil) text))
    text))
```

original was:

```
(defun x-selection-value (type)
  (let ((data-types '(public.utf16-plain-text
              com.apple.traditional-mac-plain-text
              public.file-url))
    text tiff-image)
    (while (and (null text) data-types)
      (setq text (condition-case nil
             (x-get-selection type (car data-types))
           (error nil)))
      (setq data-types (cdr data-types)))
    (if text
    (remove-text-properties 0 (length text) '(foreign-selection nil) text))
    (setq tiff-image (condition-case nil
             (x-get-selection type 'public.tiff)
               (error nil)))
    (when tiff-image
      (remove-text-properties 0 (length tiff-image)
                  '(foreign-selection nil) tiff-image)
      (setq text (mac-TIFF-to-string tiff-image text)))
    text))
```